# Timeout when connecting to Postgres server on same machine

Tags: node.js, postgresql, networking, node-postgres

I have a PostgreSQL 13 server installed on my (Windows 10) laptop from development purposes.
I started developing a nodejs/express app with it, which worked fine, untill it suddenly stopped working several days later without any changes to the code.

I've been able to reproduce the error with the following script:

```
const pg = require('pg');

const db = new pg.Pool({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    user: "postgres",
    password: "admin",
    database: "postgres"
});

db.query('SELECT NOW()').then(result => {
    console.log(result.rowCount);
}).catch(console.error);
```

The error is:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

That wouldn't be *too* weird, howerever, if I run `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres`, supply `admin` as the password and type out `SELECT NOW()`, I *do* get the current time. Connecting from Python also works.

To make it even weirder, I also have PostgreSQL 13 and Node installed on my Desktop computer. When I run the script there it works! (Well, I get wrong password errors, which is understandable, and means it at least connects.)

To make it **even** weirder, when I try to connect from my laptop to my desktop, it works, and when I connect from my desktop to my laptop, it **also** works.

Also, it doesn't work on my laptop even when changing `localhost` to the actual internal IP. (Then it doesn't time out, but hangs forever.)

Somebody please help. I have no idea whatsoever to what could prevent me from connecting only using Node.js withing the same machine.

`pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             192.168.1.1/23          scram-sha-256
```

Comment: What information is there in the Postgres and system logs when you attempt the connection? When you say internal IP, do you mean `127.0.0.1` or something else?

Comment: @adrian-klaver Nothing gets logged into `data/log/`. By internal IP I mean the local-network DHCP-assigned 192.168.1.1/23 address.

Comment: What does the OS system log show?. Have you tried using `127.0.0.1` as the host?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The event viewer shows nothing from any relevant timeframes except for Windows Security Audits and and HP Comm Recovery messages. I have tried both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, which give timeout errors.

Comment: Then the only thing I can figure is that the Node `pg` module on your laptop is not compatible with Postgresql 13. To hazard a guess it would have to do with the `scram-sha-256` auth setting in `pg_hba.conf`. You might try setting that to `md5` instead. Per here [Auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-password.html) that will work with `scram` passwords also.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver But it can connect to the database on my desktop, which is also scram-sha-256 authenticated PostgreSQL 13 installed a few days later. And it used to work on my laptop, before it inexplicably broke after not using it for a few days.

Comment: Well something changed.  Crank up the logging in your Postgres log and see what happens when you connect. I am not a Node user, still the examples here [Pool](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) don't seem to match your code. Are you sure the code is correct?